# SQL: Select AS with IF condition

Tags: sql, database

I have a MSG table with columns `ITEM_ID, SELLER_ID, MSG_SENDER_ID and MSG_RECEIVER_ID` to record the conversation between a buyer and seller for an item.

| ITEM_ID | SELLER_ID | MSG_SENDER_ID | MSG_RECEIVER_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 1 |

I need to select SELLER and BUYER. In this case seller = 1 and buyer = 2. The logic is: if SELLER_ID == MSG_SENDER_ID then buyer = MSG_RECEIVER_ID. then if SELLER_ID == MSG_RECEIVER_ID then buyer = MSG_SENDER_ID.

What should the query be like?

Comment: Also add the expected result. A [mcve]. And add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT *
      ,CASE 
            WHEN SELLER_ID = MSG_SENDER_ID THEN 'buyer'
            WHEN SELLER_ID = MSG_RECEIVER_ID THEN 'seller'
        END AS type
FROM MSG
```